# Cordova FileTransfer cannot find file

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

Using Cordova FileTransfer plugin, I'm trying to upload an image (which is correctly displayed in an img tag), but I keep getting a code 1 error (FileTransferError.FILE_NOT_FOUND_ERR) executing on browser.

Using this code:

```
    var options: FileUploadOptions = {
        params: {
            extraParam: "some value"
        },
        fileName: "filename.jpg"
    };

    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    ft.upload(
        imageURI, URL,
        (result) => console.log("success"),
        (error) => console.log("error: " + JSON.stringify(error)),
        options);
```

I get the image URI from the src attribute of an HTMLImageElement, it looks like
http://localhost:8000/img/file.jpg.
I tried also to wire a relative path like img/file.jpg, with no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: just try using ip instead of localhost

Comment: @Gandhi, I tried with no success. I need to say that the file is correctly loaded in the page, and also there is no loading error logged by the Cordova file server